# Cant get field to show in the aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have db of the kind below

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fd0bbae2fc35ebd500d91c6"
  },
  "movie_id": "0055657",
  "title": "The Alfred Hitchcock Hour",
  "year": "1962",
  "length": 50,
  "crew": [
    {
      "person_id": "0381638",
      "give_name": "Gordon Hessler",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1390262400000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1390089600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "producer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0516093",
      "give_name": "Norman Lloyd",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1740355200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "producer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0365661",
      "give_name": "Joan Harrison",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1972944000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "776822400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "producer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0171050",
      "give_name": "Herbert Coleman",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1958342400000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1002067200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "producer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0001888",
      "give_name": "Robert Douglas",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1898035200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "916012800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "producer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0751063",
      "give_name": "Charles Russell",
      "role": "producer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0277643",
      "give_name": "Morton S. Fine",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1673222400000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "668304000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "producer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0295053",
      "give_name": "David Friedkin",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1824595200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "214185600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "producer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0723629",
      "give_name": "David Lowell Rich",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1556928000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1003622400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "producer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0458033",
      "give_name": "Alf Kjellin",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1572912000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "576201600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0628149",
      "give_name": "Joseph M. Newman",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1906156800000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1137974400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0320637",
      "give_name": "Bernard Girard",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1636502400000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "883440000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0103975",
      "give_name": "John Brahm",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-2410128000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "403228800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0678928",
      "give_name": "Joseph Pevney",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1839715200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1211068800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0366314",
      "give_name": "Harvey Hart",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1304553600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "627609600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0828720",
      "give_name": "Robert Stevens",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1548892800000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "618451200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0001888",
      "give_name": "Robert Douglas",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1898035200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "916012800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0806915",
      "give_name": "Jack Smight",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1414281600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1062374400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0295053",
      "give_name": "David Friedkin",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1824595200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "214185600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0516093",
      "give_name": "Norman Lloyd",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1740355200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0189075",
      "give_name": "Alan Crosland Jr.",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1623801600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1008633600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0202297",
      "give_name": "Herschel Daugherty",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1867622400000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "731289600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0001628",
      "give_name": "Sydney Pollack",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1120435200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1211760000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0723629",
      "give_name": "David Lowell Rich",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1556928000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1003622400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0070670",
      "give_name": "Laslo Benedek",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-2045779200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "700272000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0604702",
      "give_name": "Harry Morgan",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1727136000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1323216000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "director"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0108745",
      "give_name": "James Bridges",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1070150400000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "739324800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0805748",
      "give_name": "Henry Slesar",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1343001600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1017705600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0743232",
      "give_name": "Arthur A. Ross",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1574985600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1226361600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0088645",
      "give_name": "Robert Bloch",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1664409600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "780278400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0370883",
      "give_name": "Alfred Hayes",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1852675200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "492825600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0330664",
      "give_name": "William D. Gordon",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1640736000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "681955200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0506087",
      "give_name": "Richard Levinson",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1117238400000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "542505600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0512894",
      "give_name": "William Link",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1137542400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0277643",
      "give_name": "Morton S. Fine",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1673222400000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "668304000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0295053",
      "give_name": "David Friedkin",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1824595200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "214185600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0613732",
      "give_name": "Joel Murcott",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1728259200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "256435200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0203405",
      "give_name": "Lewis Davidson",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1363305600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "645580800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0528530",
      "give_name": "Barré Lyndon",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-2315865600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "88646400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0275848",
      "give_name": "Richard Fielder",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0375355",
      "give_name": "Lukas Heller",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1244937600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "594432000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0558577",
      "give_name": "Richard Matheson",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1384214400000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1371945600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1709351",
      "give_name": "Lou Rambeau",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0082941",
      "give_name": "John Bingham",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1930089600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "586828800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0062629",
      "give_name": "Paul Winterton",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1952985600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "978912000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0269623",
      "give_name": "William Fay",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1637020800000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "347155200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1664770",
      "give_name": "Robert Arthur",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1897948800000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-21081600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0102824",
      "give_name": "Leigh Brackett",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1706313600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "258940800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0437320",
      "give_name": "Henry Kane",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1707646",
      "give_name": "Andrew Benedict",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0344181",
      "give_name": "Davis Grubb",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1591920000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "333244800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0587743",
      "give_name": "Oscar Millard",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1951430400000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "660528000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0001969",
      "give_name": "Ray Bradbury",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1557705600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1338854400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0728567",
      "give_name": "Jack Ritchie",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1509926400000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "419904000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1709246",
      "give_name": "Stanley Abbott",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0855704",
      "give_name": "Anthony Terpiloff",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1288224000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "254793600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0306664",
      "give_name": "John Garden",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0308177",
      "give_name": "Oliver H.P. Garrett",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-2387491200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-563587200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0531792",
      "give_name": "John D. MacDonald",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1686441600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "536112000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0698115",
      "give_name": "V.S. Pritchett",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-2178835200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "858816000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1709355",
      "give_name": "Samuel Rogers",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1713448",
      "give_name": "Charles Runyon",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0941280",
      "give_name": "Cornell Woolrich",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-2085264000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-40003200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0068666",
      "give_name": "George Bellak",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1600992000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1035244800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0086671",
      "give_name": "Nicholas Blake",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-2072736000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "75340800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1707649",
      "give_name": "Amber Dean",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-2116108800000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "486604800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0225779",
      "give_name": "Francis Didelot",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0260012",
      "give_name": "Lee Erwin",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1997740800000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "66441600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0294016",
      "give_name": "Celia Fremlin",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1752537600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1245110400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1113277",
      "give_name": "Robert Gould",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0375925",
      "give_name": "Elizabeth Hely",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0452134",
      "give_name": "Roland Kibbee",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1763337600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "460512000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1707657",
      "give_name": "Hilda Lawrence",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0523269",
      "give_name": "Marie Belloc Lowndes",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-3200083200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-698457600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0748111",
      "give_name": "Mann Rubin",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1327276800000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1381536000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0843387",
      "give_name": "Julian Symons",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1817424000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "785203200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1709380",
      "give_name": "Robert Twohy",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0912451",
      "give_name": "Douglas Warner",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1713404",
      "give_name": "Robert Branson",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1709265",
      "give_name": "Thomas H. Cannan Jr.",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1129161600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "722995200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0269879",
      "give_name": "Kenneth Fearing",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-2127945600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-268790400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1088301",
      "give_name": "C.B. Gilford",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1550793600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1280188800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0393512",
      "give_name": "Randall Hood",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1306627200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "209001600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1709303",
      "give_name": "S.B. Hough",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1493117",
      "give_name": "Veronica Parker Johns",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1707659",
      "give_name": "Margaret Manners",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0549924",
      "give_name": "Max Marquis",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1622374",
      "give_name": "Margaret Millar",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1732665600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "764640000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1709337",
      "give_name": "Emily Neff",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1709357",
      "give_name": "Sidney Rowland",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0811772",
      "give_name": "Boris Sobelman",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1902873600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "33955200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0881501",
      "give_name": "Gabrielle Upton",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0920229",
      "give_name": "H.G. Wells",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-3259180800000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-738028800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0923839",
      "give_name": "Hugh Wheeler",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1823644800000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "554256000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0943909",
      "give_name": "John Wyndham",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-2097964800000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-25574400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1093689",
      "give_name": "Avram Davidson",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1473552000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "736819200000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1707308",
      "give_name": "Richard Deming",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1725840000000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "431568000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1709281",
      "give_name": "Nigel Elliston",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1709300",
      "give_name": "Larry M. Harris",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "1713422",
      "give_name": "James Holding",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0397208",
      "give_name": "Clark Howard",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0414669",
      "give_name": "W.W. Jacobs",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-3354998400000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-831081600000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0421862",
      "give_name": "Selwyn Jepson",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0561260",
      "give_name": "André Maurois",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-2664489600000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-70588800000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0624776",
      "give_name": "Helen Nielsen",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1615507200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1024704000000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0924781",
      "give_name": "Ethel Lina White",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0996167",
      "give_name": "James Yaffe",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-1349308800000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1496534400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "person_id": "0000033",
      "give_name": "Alfred Hitchcock",
      "birth_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "-2221171200000"
        }
      },
      "death_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "325814400000"
        }
      },
      "role": "actor",
      "character": "Alfred Hitchcock - Host"
    }
  ],
  "ratings": [
    {
      "source": "IMDb",
      "rating_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1509408000000"
        }
      },
      "score": 8.6
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to query the crew that is still alive, hence where crew.death_date is missing, and then sort them by birth date.
I achieved it this way as it was very simple

```
db.movie.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$crew"},
    {"$match": {"crew.death_date": {"$exists": false}}},
    {"$project": {"crew.give_name": 1, "crew.birth_date": 1}},
    {"$sort": {"crew.birth_date": 1}},
])
```

However the result is comprised only of the "crew.give_name" and not of the birth date despite i projected it.
If I remove "$sort" then the birth date is indeed displayed in the result but its not sorted.
Anybody can help me out?

Comment: [your code](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3dQv_fqYcc5) is actually working fine. The reason you are seeing missing `birth_date` field is because some of your `crew` entry is missing the `birth_date` field. According to the [sort order](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#ascending-descending-sort), they are put at the start when you are sorting in ascending order. If you observe later entries, you can see the field is there.

Comment: Alright that explains it, I guess I should also specify crew.birth_date: {"$exists": true} to make it show then.